# ReferenceError: type is not defined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-fullstack

I got this error while testing, ***ReferenceError: type is not defined*** how to resolve it ??
but there is no variable named "type" here.

`jestExpect(sample.datasource-type).toEqual('metadata');`

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, clear error message details, and stacktrace, debugging information, etc...

Comment: check now. i have updated the question

Comment: not sure who closed it but it is very easy to reproduce and is not a typo but as I said a quirk of how the dot notation works in JS with regard to arbitrary properties on JS objects.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript does not accept hyphens in identifiers. You need to replace `sample.datasource-type` with `sample["datasource-type"]`

Comment: Yus it solved the issue. thanks for the help

Comment: can you accept the answer plz ?